# How to control defaultChecked in input tag at react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to control initial defaultChecked in input tag at react?

I am korean wanna be front-end engineer. I am not goot at using English.
I have a question at react.

I make the survey page and there are some options to choose one. And then I want to make modify function at survey page. So, I can render another input tags value but I can not render options value that will be defaultChecked value.

I set up like this `defaultChecked={checkedValue}`
and `const [checkedValue, setCheckedValue] = useState(false)`
and then I can receive value from database. Here is from below,
value is options value before surveied data from database.

SO I want to say

- when i click edit button, i want to appear option value from received database data and then i want to control defaultChecked value is true or false.

Please, help me.

thank you for reading this article that is not good English.

```
const EditSurveyForm = ({ data, handleClick, name }) => {
  const getToken = window.sessionStorage.getItem("token");
  const [value, getValue] = useState("");
  const [checkValue1, getCheckValue1] = useState(false);
  const [checkValue2, getCheckValue2] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const ac = new AbortController();
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5000/content/${contentId}`, {
        headers: { "x-access-token": getToken },
      })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.data.Content) {
          getValue(res.data.Content[name]);
          handleOption();
        }
      });
  }, [value]);

  const handleOption = () => {
    if (value === 1) {
      getCheckValue1(true);
    }
    if (value === 2) {
      getCheckValue2(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <div className={data.name}>{data.data}</div>
        <SurveyContainer>
          <span>
            약1
            <div>
              <input
                defaultChecked={checkValue1}
                type="radio"
                name={`question${data.id}`}
                value="1"
                onClick={e => handleClick(data.name, e.target.value)}
                className="option1"
              />
            </div>
          </span>
          <span>
            <br></br>
            <div>
              <input
                defaultChecked={checkValue2}
                type="radio"
                name={`question${data.id}`}
                value="2"
                onClick={e => handleClick(data.name, e.target.value)}
                className="option2"
              />
            </div>
          </span>
        </SurveyContainer>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default EditSurveyForm;
```

Please, help me. Thank you.

Comment: What's the response from your API looks like?

Comment: HI, I am late to reply. I get data from API like this  data.name = 4, data.name = 5. It depends on check the value before. Data type is number.